# Onclick the button to export excel in XPages

Tags: javascript, excel, export, xpages

I found the code on the website: https://www.xpagedomino.com/2015/02/xpage-export-to-excel-using-javascript.html

Now I have :

1. a view
2. one button

---

I want to use the button to export the excel.

The following is I already tried the code：

In the button(Client-side) :

```
var viewPanel1Id = "view:_id1:viewPanel1"
var htmltable = document.getElementById(viewPanel1Id);
var html = htmltable.outerHTML;
window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(html));
```

But the button was no response...

How can I export to excel?????

---

The following is the code of XPages

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
<xp:button value="Export5" id="button5">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript: var viewPanel = document.getElementById("#{id:viewPanel1}");
 var html = viewPanel.outerHTML;
window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(html));}]]>
</xp:this.action>
</xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
<xp:viewPanel rows="30" id="viewPanel1" viewStyle="width:100%">
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:pager partialRefresh="true" layout="Previous Group Next"
                xp:key="headerPager" id="pager1">
            </xp:pager>
        </xp:this.facets>
        <xp:this.data>
            <xp:dominoView var="view1" viewName="VEMPM03"></xp:dominoView>
        </xp:this.data>
        <xp:viewColumn columnName="LOCAL_PR_NO" id="viewColumn1"
            showCheckbox="true">
            <xp:viewColumnHeader value="prno" id="viewColumnHeader1"
                showCheckbox="true">
            </xp:viewColumnHeader>
        </xp:viewColumn>
        <xp:viewColumn columnName="PUR_DEPT_S01" id="viewColumn2">
            <xp:viewColumnHeader value="pur" id="viewColumnHeader2">
            </xp:viewColumnHeader>
        </xp:viewColumn>
        <xp:viewColumn columnName="ITEM_NAME" id="viewColumn3">
            <xp:viewColumnHeader value="name" id="viewColumnHeader3">
            </xp:viewColumnHeader>
        </xp:viewColumn>
    </xp:viewPanel>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: When opening your Developer-Tools in the Browser, is there any error message when you click the button?
And could you add the code of the XPage containing the panel and the button?

Comment: Please show the full code for the button -- are you using an action or script?  What are the contents of viewPane1/html table?

Comment: You might be better off using this project: https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Export%20any%20View%20to%20MS%20Excel or this: https://poi4xpages.openntf.org/

Comment: @LarsMigula It's didn't show any error message in the browser. Add the code containing the panel and the button?

Comment: @teleman It's already full code for the button. I using the script.

Answer (score 3):

Your Button executes ServerSide Script. When using <xp:this.script> it worked for me.

```
    <xp:button value="Export5" id="button5">
      <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[ 
                var viewPanel = document.getElementById("#{id:viewPanel1}");
                var html = viewPanel.outerHTML;
                window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(html));]]>
  </xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Comment: This should be the answer-- use 'this.script' instead of 'this.action'.  No refresh or any of that.

Comment: OK! After I try the code again, that's can be work. Thanks, everyone !!!!!

Comment: Please accept the answer as the correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Please accept the answer as the correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

This may not fix your problem, but the line below is a better way to reference an element by its id in csjs:

```
 var viewPanel1Id = document.getElementById("#{id:viewPanel1}")
```

Comment: Yes, better to use this!

Comment: Okay!Thanks! I will use this.