# (XPages/Javascript)Click the button to export excel

Tags: javascript, excel, export, xpages

I already asked this question, like this: [Onclick the button to export excel in XPages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63407992/onclick-the-button-to-export-excel-in-xpages)

But this tip just exports the view's value.

I want to set more values in the excel, and the page just shows a part of the info into the view.

The view just like this:

[image]

And the excel just like this:

[image]

How to achieve this kind of excel export?

Answer (score 2):

So you want to use the whole view, not just the visible parts. Whole, both for columns and rows. Your best course of action is to head over to OpenNTF.org and look for the project [Poi4Xpages](https://poi4xpages.openntf.org/). It allows you to generate real xls(x) files including formula and formatting. There you can loop through a view as you wish.

The samples and documentation should get you started.

See: https://my.webgate.biz/poi/documentation.nsf/viewdoc.xsp?docid=ConfigureExcelExport

Comment: Can you share the results of the execution?Thanks!!!!!

Comment: I already downloaded the POI4Xpages, which file should I install??

Comment: You should follow the install guide at https://my.webgate.biz/poi/documentation.nsf/viewdoc.xsp?docid=installguide

Comment: So sorry...I saw the step02, I didn't have the "eclipse update site(8.5.3)" to choose to create......

Comment: @Ariel Please accept the answer as the correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

We use this in a similar fashion. You can use styles (CSS) to display or hide cells. You have to add the style information on the page itself, not in a separate file, otherwise Excel won't use them.